# Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'D:\'

Tags: node.js, express, npm, npm-install

[got this error while using node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpjnh.png)

tried to initialize the node project and got this error after hitting npm i command:

```
  PS D:\Task-Manager-APi>npm i
```

npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path D:
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'D:'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'D:'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR

Comment: Please post the error as a text, and not an image.

Comment: try again as administrator